# Forwarding a Keystroke to another Control in WinForms

Tags: winforms, winapi, keyboard

I am receiving a keystroke in a `Form` object's `OnKeyDown`. When some conditions are met (such as the keystroke is a printable character and not a hotkey) I want to forward the key to a text control on the form and set focus to the text control so the user can continue typing. I am able to decode the character typed using `MapVirtualKey` but I get only the "unshifted" character (always upper case). Using `ToUnicodeEx` seems like too much of a PITA.

What is the best way to do this? Isn't there a way to simply forward the Windows message itself?

Can't I intercept the `ProcessKeyPreview` or some such and forward it to the text control's `ProcessKeyPreview`? Any ideas along similar lines?

**Bump:** No answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this on a single form with the following

```
private void MyFunkyForm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // to avoid duplicate letters in textbox :-)
    if (textBox2.Focused == false)
    {

        // get the char from the Keycode
        char inputChar = (char)e.KeyCode;
        if (char.IsLetterOrDigit(inputChar))
        {
            // if letter or number then add it to the textbox
            textBox2.Text += inputChar;
        }

        // set focus
        textBox2.Focus();
        // set cursor to the end of text, no selection
        textBox2.SelectionStart = textBox2.Text.Length;
    }
}
```